# replacing NA groping by id and computing the latest date - R

Tags: r, date, group-by, nan

I have this `df`:

```
            id       date
230       1066 2018-01-22
231       1066 2018-01-26
232       1066 2018-01-21
233       1066 2018-01-20
234       1066 2018-01-18
235       1066 2018-01-19
236       1066 2018-01-22
237       1017       <NA>
238       1017 2018-03-09
239       1017       <NA>
240       1017       <NA>
241       1017       <NA>
242       1017 2018-05-16
243       1017 2018-05-16
244       1017 2018-03-29
245       1017 2018-05-16
246       1017 2018-05-16
247       1017       <NA>
248       1017       <NA>
249        442 2018-05-20
250        442 2018-05-17
```

Where I need to group them by id given the latest date, but when the group has `NA` it will give the `NA` instead the latest date (max) value:

`aggregate(df$date, by=list(df$id), max)`

```
76     1066 2018-04-09
77     1017       <NA>
78      442 2018-05-20
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to replace them. I tried to replace them with 0 (as I'm looking for the max value):

```
df[is.na(df$date),c("date")] <- 0
```

But it gave me this error:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

And I don't want to change the date to numeric because after this (when each id will have only one date) I will need to extract the month and year per id to do some conditional computations. And the last is very simple with `month()` and `year()` from `lubridate`.

Comment: There is `na.rm` argument for `max` `aggregate(df$date, by=list(df$id), max, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: You cannot. If you insist on keeping the result as a Date-classed object, then there is no valid "0" value.

Comment: If it is to replace the NA with max date, then `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(date = zoo::na.aggregate(date, max, na.rm = FALSE))`

Comment: @42- I don't need to replace them with the "0" value. I just need to replace the NA with some thing or trying to figure out a way to ignore them, in order to get the latest date per id.

Comment: @akrun it gives me this error: `Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column str is of unsupported class POSIXlt/POSIXt.` (The class of `df$date` is Date, for the reasons explained in the topic)

Comment: If you will specify a valid Date then you can assign to it using `[.Date<-`. I don't know why akrun is suggesting using dplyr to convert to POSIXct, since the question involves a Date classed vector.

Comment: @Chris I thought you had `POSIXct` or `Date` class as POSIXlt` is not supported in `dplyr`.  Try `df %>% mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date))` and then do the conversion

Comment: Also don't work. `Error: Column str is a date/time and must be stored as POSIXct, not POSIXlt.` By the way, what means with the `str` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% group_by(id)  %>% summarize(max(date,na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id `max(date, na.rm = T)`
  <int>                 <date>
1   442             2018-05-20
2  1017             2018-05-16
3  1066             2018-01-26
```